# Task.run not working for Database connections

Tags: c#, ado.net, task, task-parallel-library, console-application

When I am using Task.run(), the console application is automatically stopping while creating a new SqlConnection(), 
  If I use normally Its working fine. **I am unable to create a new connection in the console application.**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       new Program().startTAsk();
    }

    public async void startTAsk()
    {
           List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => this.connectDB()));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    }

    public void connectDB()
    {
        string dbDynamicConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.1.20;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Test;Password=Test";
        bool ret = false;
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(dbDynamicConnectionString))
            {

                //connect to db
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              console.writeLine("exception");
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Task.Run` works. Your code though doesn't wait for the task to complete (or even start) before exiting. It's the wrong way to execute SQL commands asynchronously too

Comment: It's not throwing any exception. The console application  exits. Even if I use await also its not working

Comment: ADO.NET has asynchronous methods like `SqlConnection.OpenAsync()` and `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync()`. You can have an `async Task Main()` in C# 7+.

Comment: I want to know why the code in above scenario is not working, Its not throwing any exceptions in debug mode.

Comment: `Even if I use await` how? What does the code look like? *Where* did you use await? On the task itself or *inside* it? The code doesn't work because it *doesn't* await for that task to finish and exits immediatellly after the call to Task.Run

Comment: I have a list of Tasks. and I used  await Task.WhenAll()  and each task connects to database and fetch details

Comment: @HemanthKrishna it is because you start a task and do not wait for it to complete. Add `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of `Main` and observe what happens.

Comment: @HemanthKrishna where is that list? Where do you await it? Your `Main` method is just a `void Main()`. In any case, `Task.Run()` works, which is why you have the problem in the first place. If it didn't, the SQL command would complete before `Task.Run` returned. If you want help post your *actual* code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Its in another solution. Both are exiting at the same line so i posted this code

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks, this is working. Is there any otherway ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If i make startTAsk() method async and wrote await before Task.run(), Still I am facing same issue

Comment: @HemanthKrishna this code has an obvious bug. You forgot to await the tasks. Post the *actual code you tried*.  `Console.ReadKey()` only covers up the bug. BTW your code never adds the task to the list

Comment: @HemanthKrishna I wouldn't say that is working exactly. You could still possibly hit a key and return before your task is done. But yes, there are other ways. For one, just don't use `Task.Run` at all. Two, go async and `await` as mentioned above - but you should put effort into learning async/await before you try to use it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos posted the actual code.I used await Still my console is exiting in the middle.

Comment: @HemanthKrishna what you posted won't even compile. You can't have an `await` without an `async`

Comment: @Crowcoder I need to parallely call so many tasks at the same time. So i have chosen Task.Run()

Comment: @HemanthKrishna and you *still* don't await the tasks. `await Task.WhenAll()` is an asynchronous operation itself. `async void` on the other hand is *only meant for event handlers*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, Changed the method. Forgotten to change in the question.  In my case what I have to do to make it work ?

Task.whenall() will wait for all tasks to complete right ?

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()) is working in my case

Answer (score 1):

This code has an obvious problem - it never waits for the task to complete and exits before it even starts.

There's nothing wrong with Task.Run to begin with, but it *does* start another thread. SqlClient offers true asynchronous methods though which don't take up a thread just to block it while waiting.

The code could be rewritten this way:

```
static async Task RunSomeCommand(string connString)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var cmd=new SqlCommand(...);
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          console.writeLine("exception");
    }
}   

static async Task RunManyCommands()
{
   var listOfConnections=new List<string>();
   //Somehow load all connection strings
   var tasks = from cn in listOfConnections
               select RunSomeCommand(cn);
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

class Program
{
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Starting");
      await RunManyCommands();
      Console.WriteLine("Finished");
   }
}
```

`RunSomeCommand` opens a connection and executes a command asynchronously. `RunManyCommands` starts multiple asynchronous operations and awaits all of them to complete. Finally `Main` itself *awaits* `RunManyCommands` to finish before terminating

Comment: Task.waitAll() also working instead of await Task.WhenAll() and making the main () method async